# how to search for a text in a string and replace with its value

Tags: python

I need to search for image_bid in string `s`and if exists need to replace that string with its value `DEBUG` in this case,I tried the following but doesn't seem to work,can anyone suggest how can I do that?

```
import re
s = "cols/sel/Pkg/Bin/LA/${image_bid:DEBUG}/"

match = re.search('image_bid:(\w+)',s)
print match.group(1)

if match:
    final_value = s.replace('image_bid:(\w+)',match.group(1))
print final_value

MY OUTPUT:-
cols/sel/Pkg/Bin/LA/${image_bid:DEBUG}/

Expected output:-
cols/sel/Pkg/Bin/LA/DEBUG
```

Comment: Why are you expecting the `${` and `}/` to disappear?

Comment: thats not an acceptable path...

Comment: I just meant that your implementation doesn't really try to remove them. I wasn't sure if that was intentional or an oversight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The method replace() returns a copy of the string in which the
>   occurrences of old have been replaced with new, optionally restricting
>   the number of replacements to max.

It doesn't seem like the `replace` method for string support regular expression, use `re.sub` instead:

```
if match:
    final_value = re.sub(r'\${image_bid:\w+}',match.group(1), s)
print final_value
# cols/sel/Pkg/Bin/LA/DEBUG/
```

Comment: i need the trailing front slash `/` to be present like `cols/sel/Pkg/Bin/LA/DEBUG/`

Comment: You can remove the `/` from the pattern so that it will not get replaced. It's added because it doesn't show in your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like

```
final_value = re.sub(r'\$\{image_bid\:(\w+)\}/', r'\1', s)
```